# Sending Tez without revealing my balance

Tags: privacy

How should I proceed if I want to send some Tez to a friend without revealing my balance?

An approach could be to deposit a larger sum to a well-known exchange and then to withdraw part of it to the address of my friend (depositing the exact sum would be too obvious with an explorer).
This would cost me the withdrawal fees and the coins would not be in my custody for a short time (therefore needing to trust the exchange).

Is there a safer way at the moment?

Comment: There's no great way at the moment but your idea behind creating some accounts and transferring between them is the best way for now. Don't forget to vote on this https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/commit/1cd31972ed2de9deee77592b8ffc5fb3d0170d1a

Answer (score 0):

Sapling contract can helpd, here is a guide how to
https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmZBqtv4FnJP8S7vwHXvGRjipDVuok5szDoCcunx4VDD8P